# How to build a blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

I want to build a blockchain similar to that of Ethereum but not from scratch. Are there any platforms that allow you to build your blockchain? I have came across `MultiChain` but not sure whether this is a good choice. Can I get some good platforms that allow to build blockchain?

Comment: Read the Bitcoin white paper and implement all those in any language that you are familiar with.

Comment: Do you intend to create a private blockchain?

Comment: @variable No. I want to create a public blockchain to host my cryptocurrency.

Answer (score 5):

Before going to the answer how to build a blockchain and not doing it from scratch, it would make sense to know *why* you want to do this? Building Bbockchain technology needs very specialized software engineering skillset which most of us do not have. The mere fact that you are asking this question hints that if this is for any serious purpose you should attempt to do it. Instead, use Ethereum smart contracts and Ethereum blockchain to serve whatever decentralized innovation you are building.

Then how to build a blockchain

- Go to https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/
- Press Fork
- Edit the code and change some parameters like network name and network ids
- Build the software according to the build instructions
- Start the node on your local computer

Congratulate yourself - you just have your own blockchain running on your computer.

Comment: Thanks for response. Actually I have build a cryptocurrency on Ethereum block-chain. I know obviously Ethereum is a good choice but I wanted to have my own block-chain to host my cryptocurrency. I am aware that building a block-chain requires advanced software development skills that's why I focused  that `I don't want to build it from scratch`. I was concerned  if any platform provides easier way to make a blockchain. I came across few like `MultiChain` , `Eris` etc but not sure which of them will be a good choice to host a `cryptocurrency`?

Comment: Lets call it cloning, not building.

Comment: Just take Ethereum, change networks ids in the node software source and you have your own blockchain.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to start from scratch and also dont want to join one of the existing ones then there is a very simple solution.

Ethereum is an open source project. You can at any time just fork the project and delete, add or modify features as you see fit.

This is just an example you can do that with any existing open source blockchain implementations.

Comment: Thanks. That option was provided by [Mikko Ohtamma](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/620/mikko-ohtamaa). But what about other options like `Multichain`, it allows you to either join an existing blockchain or create a new blockchain?

Comment: I mean cloning Ethereum blockchain is OK. But are there other alternatives also avilable? Like some api to build a blockchian or something like that?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by bulding a blockchain? building the  blockchain datastructure? building a blockchain platform? building a blockchain network? building a blockchain infrastructure?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Hyperledger Fabric as well if you want to build a distributed ledger. I am not sure if they allow your own cryptocurrency or not, but they definitely have all other elements on blockchain baked in.

Answer (score 0):

Scorex can be used as a framework with standard building blocks.
However it is more work than just cloning Etherium.